# Spell casting phrases to improve roleplaying

Tags: dnd-5e, roleplaying

This is the first time I'm going to play a spell caster, Cleric specifically, and some of the spells and cantrips have 'V' for 'Verbal'.

I'm not awesome at Roleplaying, but I'd like to get better.

I'm a Life Domain Cleric devoted to Pelor, the god of sun and healing. So rather than just saying 'I touch the Rogue and cast Spare the dying', what are **canon** phrases or chants I can use to be more in depth with my character?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134584/discussion-on-question-by-asteria-spell-casting-phrases-to-improve-roleplaying).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no canonical answer to your question in the 5e range of products. There may be something to be found in the [Gord the Rogue series](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Gord%20the%20Rogue) by Gary Gygax as Pelor is a Greyhawk deity but that is a lot of research that involve books that are mostly out of print.

What I recommend instead it to look towards Fantasy Live Action Roleplaying Games that use boffer weapons. The one I played, NERO LARP, the mechanic for spell casting was to say the incant and then touch or hit a person with a soft seed filled packet.

You can [download their rule book from their website](http://nerolarp.com/e107_files/downloads/NeroRuleBook.pdf).

For example

I call upon the Earth to Cure Light Wounds
With Eldritch Force I build a Mystic Lock
I call forth a Magic Missile.
etc. They are found on page 66.

Solar is another boffer fantasy LARP with [their rulebook on line](http://www.solarinc.org/SOLAR_PHB.pdf). The spells start on Page 57.

To keep it manageable I would develop a phrase for each of the school of magic with a spot where you fill in the spell name. Then develop variations over time. For example Cure Wounds is a evocation spell so you say for all evocation spells "I call upon the Light to (spell name)". I call upon the Light to Cure Wounds.

Both NERO, Solar, and many other LARPS have been around a while. Because of this, the phrase mechanic has had a lot of playtesting behind it.

Comment: I was going to mention LARP also.  Other than that, there's just scraping the various fiction for anything a caster might have said.  Usually it's just "mumbling in an unknown tongue", though.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it's a fair question but the answer is, and is likely to remain, **there aren't any canon spellcasting chants** or anything remotely resembling such, [for historical reasons](http://geekandsundry.com/how-dd-writers-fought-the-satanic-panic/). Basically, people thought that DND involved learning how to actually cast spells, which was not helped by the fact that the early writers did do some anthropological research on various magical traditions, including contemporary ones, for their worldbuilding. There was a massive moral panic, and DND became strongly associated in the popular consciousness with Satanism, suicide, and various forms of blasphemy. So in later editions, they removed many explicit references to the supernatural, including even getting rid of demons for a while, to appease people's fears. This is why we can't have nice things.

So, you're pretty much on your own. RS Conley has a good answer using English words; if you want to sound a bit more mystical, I'm a fan of nonsense words or syllables such as those found in the PC game [Nox](https://youtu.be/IrcdZfqrHaE?t=32s); and of course there's always [faux Latin](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CanisLatinicus) like in [Harry Potter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHPqO0UnaW8) or any of a number of other fictional works. But as far as D&D canon goes, I doubt you'll find anything.